# button click inside an item in recyclerview refreshes entire activity

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I'm implementing a `RecyclerView` which has items which have a delete button, the data comes from Firebase and the delete button changes a "saved" value in firebase. this recyclerview is present in the third menu of the bottom navigation bar of the main activity.

When I click on the delete button, the entire activity restarts and the activity starts with the first menu of the bottom navigation bar

How do I stop this restarting action?

I'm attaching the `RecyclerView` adapter code below:

```
package com.demo.ash.demoapp

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Environment
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.transition.TransitionManager
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.offline_client.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.io.File

/**
 * Created by ashwin on 3/5/2018.
 */
class OfflineClientAdapter(val list: MutableList<Client>, val clientIDList:MutableList<String>): RecyclerView.Adapter<OfflineClientViewHolder>() {
    lateinit var vg: ViewGroup

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): OfflineClientViewHolder {
        val layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
        vg = parent!!
        val cellForRow = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.offline_client, parent, false)
        return OfflineClientViewHolder(cellForRow, "")
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: OfflineClientViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        val row = list.get(position)
        holder?.view?.NameView?.text = row.cname
        holder?.view?.PhnumView?.text = row.cphonenum

        holder?.clientID = clientIDList[position]

        var encodedimage = IOHelper.stringToBitmap(row.cimage)
        holder?.view?.client_image?.setImageBitmap(encodedimage)

        val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

        var database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(user?.phoneNumber)
                .child("Clients").child(clientIDList[position])

        holder?.view?.delete_client?.setOnClickListener {
            val path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            val dir = File(path.toString() + "/pranjal/saved_clients.txt")
            var clients = IOHelper.stringFromFile(dir)

            var t = JSONObject(clients)

            t.remove(clientIDList[position])

            database.child("saved").setValue(false)
        }
    }
}

class OfflineClientViewHolder(val view: View, var clientID: String): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    init{
        view.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(view.context, OfflinePatientListActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("clientID",clientID)
            view.context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is written in Kotlyn please tag your question accordingly

Comment: @Juan I'm new to StackOverflow, sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to start an activity on button click, why do you have this code?

```
view.context.startActivity(intent)
```

?

Comment: It restarts the activity, the delete button action triggers that action. The part which you suggested is needed for triggering something else

Comment: There's literally nothing else in the code shown that would do what you suggest.

Comment: Is it because of the fact that firebase data changes while clicking on delete button?

Comment: You have two on click listeners. Comment each out then add back one at a time to be certain which is causing your problem. Regarding Firebase - it's not about changing your backing data. You said your activity is restarting. Something has to be calling startActivity in that case.

Comment: Tried commenting, found out that change in data is causing the restart, besides it restarts the activity which has the adapter object, isn't it supposed to call the ValueEventListener?

Answer (score 0):

> When I click on the delete button, the entire activity restarts and the activity starts with the first menu of the bottom navigation bar

It kinda sounds like your Application is crashing. Unless you are doing something that would *unintentionally* (or intentionally?) restart said `Activity`.

It looks like you are changing the adapters data (deleting it) without calling the necessary methods to alert the adapter and recylerview that it needs to update its data. Make sure you call the necessary `.notify...()` methods after updating the data.

If the delete button is a part of the `recylerview`, make sure that you are taking it into account in the appropriate callbacks / code.

I’d make sure there aren’t any crashes going on in your 
 `.delete_client?.setOnClickListener { ... }`code.

Also make sure you aren’t accessing a null list in the other callbacks.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The app doesn't force close, isn't that proof for crashes happening in that button click event? Plus specifically changing data in firebase triggers restarting the activity(The whole code of the activity starts again, from onCreate()). Don't know what's causing this, can you look into it further?